# Why are my pavers still wet?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, physical-chemistry

I sprinkled salt on my pavers to stop the weeds growing but now they stay wet a lot longer. I expected the opposite because

1. Adding salt to water makes it boil faster.
2. Adding salt to icy roads melts the ice.

Can someone throw some light on this please?
By the way the weeds are all gone so happy days on that front.

Comment: Adding NaCl to water increases the boiling temperature. (Not much, but…)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does salt speed the transition of water from ice to vapor?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/265822/)

Comment: @JonCuster if I add salt (NaCl) to almost boiling water it will suddenly boil. I know this from extensive experience cooking spaghetti. So if, as you say, the boiling point is increased that leaves me still confused.

Comment: @Mist In that case you are just adding more nucleation sites, so you get more bubbles. You are also allowing the water to absorb energy faster, since you will be lowering the specific heat. The boiling temperature still increases though.

Comment: @BioPhysicist the comment "the dissolution of (NaCl) salt in water is slightly endothermic (5 kJ/mol)" is interesting but the water has been sitting on my pavers for hours so the temperature would be the same as if there were no salt. The rest of the post is about sublimation not evaporation so I'm not sure of the relevance unless I missed something.

Comment: OK, I get it, thanks @JonCuster & BioPhysicist. The boiling point is higher even though the bubbles appear sooner in my spaghetti water.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salt is *hygroscopic*- that it, it depresses the vapor pressure of water, making it easier for water to condense on a salty surface than it is for the resulting salty water to evaporate off that surface. So a salty surface tends to pull water vapor out of the air and hang on to it. Without the salt, the water would evaporate faster and not accumulate- this is probably what you are experiencing.